# Difference between osmocom source and rtl-sdr source?

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion, rtl-sdr

There is a **osmocom Source** and a **rtl-sdr source** block available in **GNU Radio Companion**. They seem to have the **same settings**. Is there a **difference between them**? Is one of them more up to date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a difference between them? Is one of them more up to date?

No, they are the same and here is the proof.

```
--- /usr/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks/osmosdr_source.xml   2019-04-25 18:14:38.000000000 +0300
+++ /usr/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks/rtlsdr_source.xml    2019-04-25 18:14:38.000000000 +0300
@@ -1,7 +1,7 @@
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <block>
-  <name>osmocom Source</name>
-  <key>osmosdr_source</key>
+  <name>RTL-SDR Source</name>
+  <key>rtlsdr_source</key>
   <category>Sources</category>
   <throttle>1</throttle>
   <import>import osmosdr</import>
```

Answer (score 0):

The RTL-SDR source block is effectively an Osmocom source block that has been tailored specifically for use with the RTL2832U TV tuner, also known as the [*"cheap software defined radio"*](https://osmocom.org/projects/sdr/wiki/rtl-sdr).  The RTL2832U has coined this name as they can be purchased for roughly $20 USD and works fantastically despite a few limitations from cheap hardware.  From what I gather, the Osmocom source block can be used with a variety of different SDR hardware, whereas the RTL-SDR source block should only be used with the RTL2832U.

**Note:** If you are using the RTL2832U, a custom device driver has to be loaded on prior to use with GNURadio, and can be found [here](https://www.rtl-sdr.com/rtl-sdr-quick-start-guide/).

Comment: Both have the same documentation (when double clicking on them). Both work with my RTL-SDR stick. But I am still confused that there are 2 of them. The Documentation of BOTH starts with "The osmocom source block: While primarily being developed for the OsmoSDR hardware, this block as well supports: [...]" and the rest is the same as well